# Nginx, gunicorn, python-flask application. Https is lost on redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx, https, flask, gunicorn

I am having some troubles with my application. During redirects my flask application lose the https and redirect to http instead.

I've been trying to find the solution but nothing works.

My nginx configuration for the application (location /) is as follows:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:5400;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-port 443;
proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

(Some examples on the internet says to use "X-Forwarded-Proto". I've tried that without success. And also to use "ssl" or "https" as value on that parameters.

A simple print in the flask application (before_request:) shows that it is still http-requests made event though i use https between client and nginx.

```
print(request.environ["wsgi.url_scheme"])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If your application ignores the `X-Forwarded` headers for setting the scheme in http 3xx responses, you could try setting one or more `proxy_redirect` rules:

```
proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning**. Making unwanted HTTP redirects is a **security flaw** as in those requests the connection is not encrypted!!

The only solution here is to correctly configure NGINX and GUNICORN to allow Flask to use the correct headers.

NGINX config should contain at least following directives:

```
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
proxy_pass              http://appserver:5000;
```

And, this is the real solution here, GUnicorn **must be started with** the `--forwarded-allow-ips` parameter.

Following is how I start it in production, fixing also the real IP address in logs (beware to complain to the GDPR :P ):

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=FALSE gunicorn              \
                        --access-logfile '-' \
                        --access-logformat '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s" "%({X-Real-IP}i)s"' \
                        -b :5000             \
                        --forwarded-allow-ips="*" \
                        app:app
```

You should **NEVER** send a request in HTTP. The first and only redirect should be the `/`.